# What is code for installing a dishwasher in the U.S.?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, dishwasher

I will be replacing my dishwasher and I am curious what is the current code for the wiring of the dishwasher.

Comment: Does the dishwasher have a cord and plug, or just a place to land a wire and connect it?

Comment: I do not have the dishwasher currently to look at it, but I believe it has a place to land the wires.

Comment: I've answered, but it would be rather helpful if you could include some more information such as your location, and the results of any investigating you've done to try and locate a feed for it.

Comment: I will Tim, I know the current dishwasher has a a place to terminate wires. I will add some photos tomorrow of the current set dishwasher and what is done when I get the new one.

Comment: It's an appliance, so you pretty much just connect it per the instructions (which should be to code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're in the US (though I can't imagine it being much different elsewhere, but do check!) ...

Be sure to check the label, but most dishwashers run perfectly happy on a 15A circuit. If a dedicated circuit to the dishwasher isn't possible, you can come out of a general receptacle circuit that isn't otherwise utilized in the kitchen, depending on the rating of the dishwasher. What you want to avoid is a mixer and toaster *and* dishwasher using the same circuit at once. You may have to do some investigating. Go for the dedicated circuit if that's possible.

NEC 210.8.D specifies that dishwashers must be GFCI protected, and doesn't differentiate between cord-and-cap or direct connection (as it defines an outlet as any connection). ***However***, not all states have adopted this because of the nuisance factor of older appliances and older GFCIs that tended to be overly-sensitive to fluctuation on the neutral leg. Check what applies in your state; you may want to just use a GFCI breaker on the branch circuit feeding the dishwasher as that's the easiest way to be sure, or be absolutely certain you're coming out of the "load" side of a GFCI receptacle that won't otherwise see much use.

Otherwise, if the dishwasher has a cord and cap, you should have an *appliance receptacle* installed where it can be reached. An appliance receptacle is an outlet with only one place to plug something in. If your state doesn't require the dishwasher being GFCI protected, they'll *absolutely* want to make sure you use a single appliance receptacle so nothing else can be connected to the unprotected receptacle. Finally, if directly wiring it, just make sure you use the appropriate connector if the vendor doesn't supply one.

Be kind to your future self, or anyone else that has to pull the dishwasher out in the future to service it by leaving enough cable to be able to pull it out and off to the side. Make sure the cable is secured properly wherever it is fed, and protected anywhere that it may be exposed on its path to the dishwasher.

If uncertain or uneasy - you probably want to call an electrician.

Comment: +1 for the 'be kind' suggestion! Nothing more infuriating than to realize they only left 1' of slack in the wiring when you go to pull it out.

Comment: Can you explain the restriction against putting a dishwasher on a GFCI? thanks

Comment: @DaveInCaz Just a nuisance factor, GFCI receptacles tend to trip on certain kinds of appliance motor loads, dishwashers being one of them. If the appliance is listed and approved, there's no chance of it causing a person to come into ground potential while using it, so they're not _required_ to be on a GFCI. If you want or need to use a GFCI then it's up to you, and if it doesn't trip frequently, then no big deal :) Most people use dedicated non-GFCI appliance receptacles (has a single plug) just to avoid constant nuisance tripping.

Comment: Current code requires gfci protection NEC 210.8.D . your state may not have adopted this section of code as my state does not require them but the requirement is in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Current code suggests a dedicated line run to the breaker box for use with the dishwasher. 2008 NEC indicates that the kitchen should have two 20 amp counter top circuits to run small appliances.[So you can run a microwave and a toaster at the same time.] The NEC also says that those circuits should not be used for anything else.

-In a retrofit situation, you could tap into the counter top circuit if there is no other option. Unfortunately, with this arrangement, the motor and heating element will consume most of your available amps leaving you in a situation where you cannot use other things while the dishwasher is running.

On use of grounding and GFCI's... No matter what you do, ground the dishwasher to a reliable ground. If you are using new wire, this will be easy. Just hook up the green or bare wire to the frame of the dishwasher and bond the other end to the breaker box ground. If it is an older home with a two wire system, You can bond the washer to copper or iron water pipe (NOT A GAS LINE!!!) For safety, be sure that the pipes are bonded to the box ground or at least earth ground.

There is no prohibition on the use of GFCI in this circuit. The electronics in new GFCI devices greatly reduces nuisance tripping. You can use a GFCI breaker, an outlet, or even a GFCI dead front. (This looks like a GFCI outlet with no holes to plug anything in- and could be mounted at the counter top for accessibility)

My installation: (Dishwasher recommends 15 - 20 amp) I ran #12 MC Flex up and over through the attic to the washer and popped out of the wall to a box attached to the inside of the cabinet next to the washer. I installed a 20A GFCI paired with the 20A breaker in the panel. I attached a #10 stranded appliance cord to the washer with a 20A plug. I did this so I could have GFCI protection and also if the washer had a significant malfunction requiring immediate reaction, the cord could be pulled out without having to find the right breaker. I have used this setup for over two years and have not had any trouble from it.

MC Flex (metal clad) is a bit of overkill for residential (unless your local building code requires it), you can just use Romex if you wish. If you are using #14 wire, do not exceed 15A. If you use #12 wire, you can safely use 20A breaker (unless your dishwasher specifies 15A only.)

Comment: Bonding to a cold water pipe in just any location IS NOT code acceptable any more. This was disallowed many years ago. 
The only thing that is allowed is if the pipe is being used as a grounding electrode and the connection is made within 5' of where the pipe enters the building since this is the only section of that pipe that is considered the grounding electrode. You can also ground/bond it to any point in the grounding electrode system or grounding electrode conductor. In such cases many times it is just as easy to run a new circuit.

Comment: If you are interested see NEC 250.130(C)

Comment: @SpeedyPetey You are right, I am soooo wrong. It is best to just not ground your equipment at all if it is not up to NEC specs... No, It is true, If you can run a new circuit, that is the best thing. But if you are in a situation where you need to add the safety of a ground and you cannot run a new line for whatever reason, is it better to utilize an older code model and be safer than doing nothing at all?

Comment: NO! It is NOT better to utilize an old code. THAT is why the code changed. Either do it right or don't do it at all.

Comment: Codes change because the change is usually better. Example: code says- outlet every 6ft. but if you are renovating an older home, sometimes it is just not practical. it is better to settle for 2 or 3 correctly wired outlets in a room than just stay with the original 1. If you are adding an appliance and you **cannot run a new line**, I would think clamping to other grounded metal is better than electrocution induced cardiac arrest. We should all strive for "CODE" but sometimes, Old houses don't cooperate.

Comment: Wow! I honestly hope you do not do this work for a living or in other people's homes! A) Receptacles are required every 12', not 6'. B) If you are renovation then the area in question MUST be brought up to code. PERIOD. That is unless you are a hack that flies under the radar. C) If you are adding an appliance you MUST also do it to code, NOT settle for what is easiest. With that said I'm out. Do what you want, just do not suggest to others to follow your ways.

Comment: A> My bad... NEC 08'- Article 210.52 (A) (1) Spacing states; Receptacles shall be installed such that no point measured horizontally along the floor line in any wall space is more than 1.8m (6' ft) from a receptacle outlet.<- is what I meant, B> It depends on how extensive the renovation. If you demo to the point that you expose old electric, you should update. if you are adding new stuff, you should update. If you significantly alter the existing system, you are obligated to update. C> I agree, Install it correctly and not worry.

Comment: On point B, many home owners try to do installations themselves. and many of them do it without any oversight. I am not saying this is a good idea, but people will do this. They will be temped to take shortcuts. Some may try to install an appliance and avoid running a new line because it is too much of an obstacle. These people will splice into a local line, even if there is no ground wire. Therefore, I will tell them how to get some ground protection. I would encourage them to get a professional to do it. But If they still go ahead with it, the old way is better than no way at all.

Comment: I appreciate that you are by the book kind of person. In spite of your people skills, You probably have a good reputation with your local inspectors. The company I worked for liked me because my work always passed. And no, this was not a slack jurisdiction either. I have not been in the trade for a few years, so there have been some changes I do't know about, But I would never give anyone advice that would put them in danger. I still stand by my original advice. By the way, Back stabs are code legal, Do you use those?

Comment: It's funny. My people skills are what gets me repeat and referral work with ZERO advertising. More work than I can handle these days. No, only complete hacks use receptacle backstabs considering their propensity and reputation for failure.
 My whole point on the grounding issue is a water pipe is NOT an effective or safe grounding path for fault current. This is why this shortcut was removed from the code many years ago. Suggesting to use this old shortcut in today's world is extremely careless IMO.

Comment: OK! We agree that the back stabs are a bad idea and should never have been introduced (That's something). I also concede that bonding to a water pipe is not ideal. In lieu of that, If running a new circuit is not possible for whatever reason, how would you suggest providing a ground for an existing circuit?

Comment: Bonding and grounding are not the same.  All metal (w/ few exceptions) including gas gets bonded. Where they get bonded is of little concern as long as they are.  Equipment grounding is what @Speedy Petey is referring to.  Its serves an entirely different purpose.